# Expected spy myMethod to have been called with: but it was never called

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

I have an issue with calling a service in a jasmine unit test method:

```
 let appService: AppService;
 beforeEach(() => {
appService = jasmine.createSpyObj("AppService",["MyMethod"]);
 appService.myMethod= jasmine.createSpy("MyMethod").and.returnValue(MyType);
 TestBed.configureTestingModule(
            {
                imports: [],
                providers: [
                    
                    { provide: AppService, useValue: appService }
}]
 it("should test service method", () => {
 expect(appService.myMethod).toHaveBeenCalledWith(12);
        
    });
}
```

This is my service method :

```
myMethod(id: number) {
    let params = new HttpParams()
      .set('id', id.toString())
    return this.Http.get(this.url + '/MyWebApiService/MyMethod', { params });
  }
```

When I execute this test I get this message : Expected spy myMethod to have been called with:  12 but it was never called. Any idea to resolve this?

Comment: In you test you need to call the method. `appService.myMethod(12)` before you assert that it was called.  Also your spy method is different casing `jasmine.createSpyObject('AppService', ['myMethod']);`.

Comment: @JasonWhite's analysis is spot on. Please correct the code as per his suggestions and your test will run just fine

Comment: Thank you, I added the call of the method and i fixed the casing, It worked for me !